# Shared sequence generator for IDs and DB scheme creation using hbm2ddl

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

all. I have an issue with DB scheme generation via hbm2ddl.
I want to use shared sequence generator for all private keys. So I defined it once in some entity.

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
 ....
}
```

Then I want to use this sequence generator for all ids.

```
public class SomeEntity1 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
  Long id;     
  ....
}

public class SomeEntity2 implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
  Long id;     
  ....
}
```

When I run hbm2ddl ant task I get an exception:

```
[hibernatetool] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR
[hibernatetool] org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR
```

Is it an issue or I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: On what database are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to generate scheme creation script for Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of this porblem was defining shared @SequenceGenerator in package-ingo.java file for package were my entities placed.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence import, i.e. `@SequenceGenerator` annotation should be presented in all classes. So make an abstract class with this annotation and extend all entities from it:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ")
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
 ....
}

public class SomeEntity1 extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
  Long id;     
  ....
}

public class SomeEntity2 extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "MY_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
  Long id;     
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response @forker. But javadoc for @SequenceGenerator says us that `"A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary key field or property. The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types)"`.